# Zero Reply Filter

Tags: feature-request

Is there a way to filter question which has got no replies?

It would be nice if such a filtering option is available in the home page along with `UnAnswered`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you hit the Unanswered button at the top, you have the option to select the [no anwser](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers) tab.

[image]